# Read Files And Insert Contents Into Database Asynchronously In VB Or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, asynchronous, lambda, anonymous-function

I need to read about 10 files each of which are ≈150 MB in size. The contents of these tab-delimited-text files need to be formatted and written to `DataTable` s which are then inserted into a database. My code *must* finish executing before ever giving control back to the code that instantiates my class.

To expedite the process, I want to utilize asynchronous programming (within my class). I figured out a way that works, but the minimalist in me would prefer to substitute a one-line `Async` function with a lambda expression or something similar. I will write the code in VB.NET, but I don't mind help in the form of C#.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Linq

///<summary>
///This BO reads all the text files from the appropriate directory and
///inserts the rows into a table. Once a file is read, it is deleted from the directory.
///</summary>

Public NotInheritable Class FileProcessing

    Public Sub Execute()

        Dim dctColumnMappings As Dictionary(Of String, String) = DictionaryMappings()
        Dim strDirectory As String = "C:\Documents\Files"
        TaskWaiterAsync(strDirectory, dctColumnMappings).Wait()
    End Sub

    ///<summary>
    ///Function that is solely used to prevent control from being passed to the code that
    ///instantiates FileProcessing
    ///</summary>

    Private Async Function TaskWaiterAsync(ByVal pstrDirectory As String, 
                                           ByVal pdctColumnMappings As Dictionary(Of 
                                           String, String)) As Task

        Await InsertAsync(pstrDirectory, pdctColumnMappings)
    End Function

    ///<summary>
    ///Function that asynchronously inserts a DataTable that contains the contents of a file.
    ///The DataTables are inserted in the order they are returned based on the 
    ///asynchronous function CreateDataTableAsync.
    ///</summary>

    Private Async Function InsertAsync(ByVal pstrDirectory As String, 
                                       ByVal pdctColumnMappings As Dictionary(Of 
                                       String, String)) As Task

        Dim lstFiles As List(Of String) = Directory.GetFiles(pstrDirectory).ToList()
        Dim vntTasksQuery As IEnumerable(Of Task(Of DataTable)) = 
            From strFilePath In lstFiles Select CreateDataTableAsync(strFilePath, 
                                             pdctColumnMappings)
        Dim lstTasks As List(Of Task(Of DataTable)) = vntTasksQuery.ToList()

        While lstTasks.Count > 0
            Dim vntFinishedTask As Task(Of DataTable) = Await Task.WhenAny(lstTasks)
            lstTasks.Remove(vntFinishedTask)
            Dim DataFile As DataTable = Await vntFinishedTask
            ///User-created class that allows database interaction.
            Dim vntSql As New SqlCon("FileDB")
            vntSql.DataTableInsert("tblFiles", DataFile)
        End While
    End Function

    ///<summary>
    ///Function that returns a dictionary mapping the appropriate subset of names of the
    ///columns from the file to the names of the columns in tblFiles.
    ///</summary>

    Private Function DictionaryMappings() As Dictionary(Of String, String)

        Dim dctColumnMappings As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, 
            String)(68, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
        ///Code that populates the dictionary.
        Return dctColumnMappings
    End Function

    ///<summary>
    ///Asynchronous function that reads from a file and returns a task containing a
    ///DataTable with the necessary values to be inserted into tblFiles.
    ///</summary>

    Private Async Function CreateDataTableAsync(ByVal pstrFilePath As String, 
                                                ByVal pdctColumnMappings As Dictionary(Of 
                                                String, String)) As Task(Of DataTable)

        Dim vntTask As New Task(Of DataTable)(Function()
                                                  Dim DataFile As New DataTable()
                                                  ///Code that populates
                                                  ///DataFile with the
                                                  ///necessary columns.

                                                  Using SR As New StreamReader(
                                                      New FileStream(pstrFilePath,
                                                         FileMode.Open,
                                                         FileAccess.Read,
                                                         FileShare.None,
                                                         8192,
                                                         FileOptions.SequentialScan Or
                                                         FileOptions.DeleteOnClose),
                                                      Encoding.UTF8, True, 8192, False)
                                                           ///Code that reads the file
                                                           ///and writes the necessary
                                                           ///formatted values into
                                                           ///DataFile.       
                                                  End Using
                                                  Return DataFile
                                              End Function)
        vntTask.Start()
        Dim FinishedDataFile As DataTable = Await vntTask
        Return FinishedDataFile
    End Function
End Class
```

The method that I would like to replace with a lambda expression is `TaskWaiterAsync`. I tried:

```
Dim vntTask As Task = New Task(Async Sub()
                                   Await InsertAsync(strDirectory, dctColumnMappings)
                               End Sub)
vntTask.Start()
vntTask.Wait()
```

The above returns control to the code that instantiates FileProcessing though. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using asynchronous programming, I opted for parallel processing. This process runs on a server with a lot of cores and threads, and it doesn't need to be responsive to a user while the job runs. I changed `InsertAsync`—named `InsertFile` below— so that it inserts the `DataTable` into the table after writing to it.

```
Dim vntFiles As IEnumerable(Of String) = Directory.GetFiles(strDirectory)
Parallel.ForEach(vntFiles, Sub(strFilePath) InsertFile(strFilePath, dctColumnMappings))
```

Answer (score 0):

the code is reasonable; there is a hard coded string though!

In the `Execute` method instead of calling `TaskWaiterAsync(strDirectory, dctColumnMappings).Wait()` couldn't the call be to the `InsertAsync` method.

```
Public Sub Execute()

    Dim dctColumnMappings As Dictionary(Of String, String) = DictionaryMappings()
    Dim strDirectory As String = "C:\Documents\Files"
    InsertAsync(strDirectory, dctColumnMappings).Wait()
End Sub
```

Just remove the `TaskWaiterAsync` method?

Comment: There are several hard-coded strings and values (e.g. the directory, the database name, the table name, the buffer size, etc.), but that's fine as I know those will always be the values (by design). I should have written all of my attempts, but the suggestion you have doesn't work. While the control is given back to the code that calls my code, the files are never inserted into the database. I debugged the code with a breakpoint on `InsertAsync`, and the code never goes passed to it.

Comment: and the code never goes passed it*^. It's in a perpetual running state.

Comment: @basketballfan22 should never have posted that as an answer. Pretty lame.

Answer (score 0):

Loaded the code into Visual Studio. Does this help?
Again call the `InsertAsync` directly.

```
Public Sub Execute()

    Dim dctColumnMappings As Dictionary(Of String, String) = DictionaryMappings()
    Dim strDirectory As String = "C:\Documents\Files"

    InsertAsync(strDirectory, dctColumnMappings)
End Sub
```

Then wait for all the files to be asynchronously read into `DataTables` before carrying on synchronously with the inserts to the database.

```
Private Sub InsertAsync(ByVal pstrDirectory As String, ByVal pdctColumnMappings As Dictionary(Of String, String)) 

    Dim lstFiles As List(Of String) = Directory.GetFiles(pstrDirectory).ToList()
    'TODO: if no files then return, nothing to do


    Dim lstTasks As IEnumerable(Of Task(Of DataTable)) =
            From strFilePath In lstFiles
            Select CreateDataTableAsync(strFilePath, pdctColumnMappings)

    ' create a single task that represents all tasks and wait for them all to complete
    Dim overall As Task(Of DataTable()) = Task.WhenAll(lstTasks)
    Task.WaitAll(overall)

    For Each lstTask As Task(Of DataTable) In lstTasks
        Dim DataFile As DataTable = lstTask.Result

        Dim vntSql As New SqlCon("FileDB")
        vntSql.DataTableInsert("tblFiles", DataFile)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: The reason I don’t want to do that is that I would like to do inserts ASAP. Instead of waiting for all the files to be read and written to `DataTable`s, I would like to insert  `DataTable`s as they finish.

Comment: @basketballfan22, that's reasonable, just make the database upload code part of the task. It's not worth the effort of trying to coordinate the end of one task with the start of another; it can be done, but simplicity. Just make both the Create and Insert the asynchronous task.

Comment: It's not that difficult or complex to coordinate `InsertAsync` and `CreateDataTableAsync`. Furthermore, by consolidating the two, I will still need my `TaskWaiterAsync` function since I won't be able to call `Await` inside `Execute` without making it asynchronous which will then cause control to be passed back to the code that calls mine. My code as is works fine and is very quick. I just wanted a way to substitute *only* `TaskWaiterAsync`. I'm reading more about asynchronous programming, and it may have something to do with the "context".